# How can I change or remove the orange login screen logo in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: ubuntu, login

[image]

After applying the dark theme to Ubuntu 22.04, one is left with an ugly orange rectangle around the Ubuntu logo on the login screen.

Image credit: https://www.neowin.net/news/canonical-releases-ubuntu-2204-lts-with-upgraded-kernel-and-gnome-desktop/

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu logo is located at `/usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png` and can be changed or removed.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the */usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png* to a different one is not persistent, once rebooted, the default logo will revert.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/427336)

Answer (score 0):

### New Logo Persistent Live Install

For a Persistent Live Install made using **mkusb** go to writable partition and create path: /upper/usr/share/plymouth/ubuntu-logo.png using your new logo renamed as ubuntu-logo.png.

If you want to change the background of the GRUB boot menu

- Copy your .png image to the target USB's usbboot partition.
- Open the boot/grub folder and then open grub.cfg
- Change "background_image /mkusb-grub-bg_800x600.png" to "background_image /[your logo's name].png